# For fundamental solutions $y_1,y_2$, there exist one and only one zero of $y_1$ between consecutive zeros of $y_2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, rolles-theorem, wronskian

> Suppose that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are a fundamental set of solutions, of the linear second order ODE $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$, on the
> interval $-\infty < t < \infty$. Show that there is one and only one
> zero of $y_1$ between consecutive zeros of $y_2$. Hint: differentiate
> the quantity $y_2/y_1$ and use Rolle's theorem.

I found an existing [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158003/92180) to this question to be unilluminating.

Here's how far I got.

Say, $a$ and $b$ are consecutive zeros of $y_2$. This would mean $\frac{y_2(a)}{y_1(a)} = \frac{y_2(b)}{y_1(b)}= 0$. Rolle's theorem now states that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $\frac{\mathrm d y_2/y_1}{\mathrm{dt}}|_{t=c} = \frac{W[y_1,y_2](c)}{y_1^2(c)}=0$. The Wronskian being zero is in contradiction with $y_1$ and $y_2$ being a fundamental set of solutions. Hence, $\frac{W[y_1,y_2](t)}{y_1^2(t)}$ is nonzero for all $t\in (-\infty,\infty)$. Furtermore, the assumption we made in using Rolle's theorem is not correct.

Namely, $y_2(t)/y_1(t)$ is not continuous and therefore also not differentiable at some points the interval $(a,b)$. This is because the denumerator $y_1(t)$ has a zero in this interval.

Is my argument correct? And how should I now prove that that this zero of $y_1$ is unique?

Context: this is question 2.1.18 of Braun's Differential Equations and Their Applications, 4th edition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ and $b$ ($a<b$) be two consecutive zeros of $y_2$; namely
$$ y_2(a)=y_2(b)=0. \tag1$$
Since $W(t)\neq0$, we can have $y_1(a)\neq0,y_1(b)\neq0$. Suppose that $y_1$ does not have zero in $(a,b)$.
Since $W[y_1,y_2](t)\neq0$ for $t\in[a,b]$, we can assume $W[y_1,y_2](t)>0$ and hence we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm d (y_2/y_1)}{\mathrm{dt}} = \frac{W[y_1,y_2](t)}{y_1^2}>0.
$$
Namely $y_2/y_1$ is strictly increasing and hence
$$ \frac{y_2(a)}{y_1(a)}<\frac{y_2(b)}{y_1(b)}. \tag2$$
Using (1) in (2), we have $0<0$ which is absurd. Thus $y_1$ has a zero in $(a,b)$. You can prove the uniqueness of zero of $y_1$.

Comment: I don't see the link between the result $0<0$ and $y_1$ having a zero in $[a,b]$. I similiarly don't see why $a$ and $b$ can't be zeros of $y_1$, and why this should matter --- aren't we looking for one unique zero *between* $a$ and $b$ --> in $(a,b)$?. Furthermore,I also don't see how I should prove the uniqueness of the zero of $y_1$.

Comment: For 1st one, you just plugin (1) into (2) and so you have $0<0$. For 2nd one,  if $y_1(a)=0$ or $y_1(b)=0$, then $W(a)=0$ or $W(b)=0$ but $W\neq0$. For the 3rd, you need to use argument by contradiction.

Comment: How do you reach the conclusion that $y_1$ has a zero in $[a,b]$, form $0<0$? And why does $y_1(a)$ or $y_1(b)$ imply $W(a) = 0$ or $W(b) = 0$? Furthermore, could you point me in the right direction on how to prove that $y_1$ has only one zero in $[a,b]$?

Comment: $0<0$ is against the assumption is that $y_1$ does not have zero in $[a,b]$.

Comment: How does $0<0$ go against the assumption that $y_1$ has no zero in $[a,b]$?

Comment: This is argument by contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116196/discussion-between-musse-redi-and-xpaul).

Comment: I've made some developments on the problem as you can see in the edited post. Could you now show why this one zero of $y_1$ is unique?